# Index maintainence in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We need to contain index sizes in PostgreSQL. We tried to explore different options

1. **Reindexing** : This involves write locks to tables which will impact application queries.
2. **Concurrent create/drop index**: This won't involve locks with following sequence
   Drop Index concurrently.
   Create Index concurrently. The concern here is when app queries are running this operations will be slow and between drop - create steps queries won't use indexes which slow down performance.

We need to achieve index size reduction while not impacting application queries at that point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create concurrently the same index with different name than the current one and then drop current and rename a new one.

But I don't think that keeping index sized at the minimum is a good idea. Some empty space in the index is most often beneficial for index performance for insert and update operations. If it blows up out of proportions you probably need more aggressive autovacuuming tuning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue with the rename is it involves "Alter index" which again involves locking (https://www.keithf4.com/cleaning-up-postgresql-bloat). We have some big tables where index and data size was significant and in order to address these growing size we already have made aggressive auto-vacuum. However, we are not clear whether that will help to contain index size and if yes how.

Comment: Yes - it requires exclusive lock on the table, but it's for much shorter duration than a index create/reindex lock, so it's easier to plan for. You can even maintain 2 identical indexes and "reindex concurrently" them alternatively. This would negatively impact insert/update performance, but if you can afford that you wouldn't need to lock table exclusively at all. As for bloat - you did not telll us how much % of index size you gain during reindex. If it's 50% then I wouldn't bother. If it's 90% then it might be worth doing.